# Bower install CERT_UNTRUSTED Error

Tags: bower, bower-install

I got the CERT_UNTRUSTED when I tried to run bower install command to install components.

For example, I got this error when I ran the following:

```
bower install bootstrap-sass-official --save
```

The output was:

```
bower                            error Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/bootstrap-sass-official failed: CERT_UNTRUSTED
```

Note: This is not a package specific error. This happens when you try to install any package, not just with bootstrap-sass-official.

Answer (score 8):

you can try setting this in .bowerrc:

```
{
"directory": "bower_components",
"registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com",
"strict-ssl": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a quick fix for this issue.  I guess the issue is happening because of my company's SSL settings.

I changed the registry search as follows (in my windows laptop) and it fixed the issue.

```
set registry.search=http://bower.herokuapp.com
```

This should work in unix systems as well, where you have to create a env variable with above key and value.

You can also change the registry setting at .bowerrc file.

You can follow as a quick and dirty fix.  Do not make it as a permanent solution.